# ${d\over dx}\int_{\sin^2 x}^{2\sin x}e^{t^2}=0$ at $x=\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis

could anyone just tell me the answer of ${d\over dx}\int_{\sin^2 x}^{2\sin x}e^{t^2}$ at $x=\pi$? I got $0$

Comment: It is not $0$. I get $-2$.

Comment: okay okay okay I am sorry

Comment: No problem, little slips are easy to make.

Comment: Hint: you have to use chain rule.

Comment: OP: Waiting a liiiitle longer before accepting answers would allow you to check whether they are correct or not. What do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

> $$ \frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(t)dt = f(b(x))b'(x)- f(a(x))a'(x).$$

Comment: There is a missing term (which is not needed if as in this case there is no dependence on $x$). Also typo, want $\frac{d}{dx}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Thanks for the comment.